# how to use two columns as condition to create a new column in the data frame which will return a Boolean value

Tags: pandas, dataframe, boolean-expression

I have an idea but i cant seem to write the right code for the problem
io want to add a column in the data frame that will return a Boolean value when two conditions are met.
the first condition is a multi-condition type
i have to find out all adults with higher education (Bachelors or Masters or Doctorate)
the second condition is a single condition
all adults who have a salary that is greater than 50K
when this two conditions are met
i want the new column to return true
if not then it should return false

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would have been better if you provided a peak of the data but anyways I can understand the scenario in some way. Here is the solution as per my understanding:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Education' : ['bachelor', 'master', 'doc', 'school', 'highschool'],
              'Salary' : [100000, 51000, 40000, 30000, 25000]})

SALARY_THRESH = 50000
req_education =  ['bachelor', 'master', 'doc']

df.apply(lambda x: x['Education'] in req_education and x['Salary'] > SALARY_THRESH,
        axis=1)
```

Comment: thanks alot it has worked